# PyInstaller exe including fpdf package is not working

Tags: python, exe, fpdf, pyinstaller

I've created an windows executable from a python script using **PyInstaller**. Since I've included the `fpdf` package, the exe is compiled without errors, but when I run it, I get an error dialog displaying the following and an OK button:

> Fatal Error!
>
> pyi_rth_pkgres returned -1

I can click the OK button and the exe process finishes.

I've looked trough the `fpdf` source code, but I don't think it has some hidden imports.

What can I do now? Does anybody has experience with including `fpdf` in a PyInstaller .exe?

Answer (score -1):

Downgrading setuptools to version 19.2 may solve the issue.